# smart contract for auto burn on every transaction

Tags: blockchain, solidity, contract

guys please guide what changes should I do?? I am deploying my own coin on testnet but getting this issue always when I try what step I am missing

My code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/…";

contract VIRUSONE is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20 ("VIRUSONE", "VONE") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

The warning ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxE8G.png)):

```
Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
```

Comment: MY CODE : pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract VIRUSONE is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20 ("VIRUSONE", "VONE"){
    _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Since Solidity 0.7, the visibility modifier is ignored for constructor ([source](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/070-breaking-changes.html#functions-and-events)). You can safely remove it and the warning disappears.

```
// removed the `public` modifier
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20 ("VIRUSONE", "VONE") {
```

instead of

```
// original code
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20 ("VIRUSONE", "VONE") {
```